# Law on certification on Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, polygon

I have a DAPP in order to certificate some data of my users, but I wish to know if exist some laws about it (for instance the format of the hash) and if there have already been any disputes addressed to the court.

For the last: is it better Etherium or Polygon?

Comment: There are no laws on certificating data on the blockchain.